# jQuery checking the length of array before each?

Tags: jquery

Quick question, do I need the if statement `.length` below?

```
var $colspans = $("td[colspan='0']");
if($colspans.length){
    $colspans.each(function(){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, since `length` will be zero ans it's not that `$colspans` will be `null`, so you're not in danger of trying to call something on nothing. It just won't iterate because there's nothing *to* iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

No. `.each` simply won't run if `.length` is Zero.

Comment: Well, it will definitely run, but will never invoke the passed function.

Comment: Right. I was going to clarify that point... but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, if `$colspans` has a length of 0 then the .each will just not be executed. No errors will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need it.  `.each` only works if the conditions are met.